# If string.Contains two numbers + "x" + one number then

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm creating a software about TV series. I need to get the "episode number" from the filename (a string) of the episode.

Examples of filenames:
"Title of the episode 2x04"
"I am another title S05E22"
"Amazing tv serie 22x2"

I thought about splitting the title part from the episode part, but the format of the filename is not the same everytime (eg. nxmm,SnnEmm, nnxm).

Here's my simple code:

```
foreach (string filename in path) {
    if (filename.Contains(*season n episode m*)) {
       // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use regex for this:

```
var list = new List<string>();

list.Add("Lost 04x01");
list.Add("Lost 04x02");
list.Add("Lost 4x3");
list.Add("Lost 4x04");
list.Add("Lost S04E05");
list.Add("Lost S04E6");

Regex regex = new Regex(@"S?\d{1,2}[X|E]?\d{1,2}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

foreach (string file in list) {
    if (regex.IsMatch(file))
    {
        // true
    }
}
```

[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bX6nX5/1)

Comment: Thank you, can I use the other one given (`(\d?\d)[xE](\d\d)`) in the same way?

Comment: @Fabio it's not complete because it doesn't match `Lost 4x3` and `Lost S04E6`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code

```
string one = "04x22";
string two = "s04e22";
if ((one.Split('x')).Count == 1)
{
    string[] res = (one.Split('e'));
    // result is res[1] 
}
else
{
    string[] res = (one.Split('x'));
    // result is res[1] 
}
```

Comment: Add different cases based on your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<season>\d+)[Ex](?<episode>\d+)");
foreach (string file in path) {
    var match = regex.Match(file);
    if (match.Success) {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["season"].Value);
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["episode"].Value);
    }
}
```

This one will match 04x22, 4x22, S04E22, etc. You should be able to tailor it to be more or less restrictive as you require.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a regular expression to find the season and episode number from the filename.

Something like `(\d?\d)[xE](\d\d)`. The first group would be the season number, the second - the episode number. See the [regex fiddle](https://www.regex101.com/r/uR2wX6/1) on explanation of the regex and a demo.

You would need to use [`Regex.Match()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match(v=vs.110).aspx) method in your code instead of `Contains()`.